# How to access a dictionary outside of a method

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox

Actually I have two question.

I have a method named `FillPersonList` which is always loaded when form start. Inside that method I access the database and put required value inside a dictionary. Previously, I can't reload the related listbox when new value is added. So I create a refresh button and when it is clicked it make that listbox datasource to null and call that `FillPersonList` method again. Well it works fine.

Now I add a textbox. When user type a word, listbox should sort itself according to that word. I do not wish to access if every time user type a word. So I declared previous dictionary outside of that method and access that method inside textBox changed method. OK, now it also work but after typing if i clear that textbox listbox only show the last value. And second problem is now if I click on refresh button It shows an "`ArgumentException`" error.

**Sample code:**

```
Dictionary<int, string> personListDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
private void FillPersonList()
{
  //connect to database
  SqlCommand prsonListCmd = new SqlCommand(SQL_QUERY, conn);
  SqlDataReader dr = prsonListCmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
      {
       while (dr.Read())
        {
          //Access value
          personListDictionary.Add(key, value); //Here ArgumentException occurs
        }
      }
      PersonList.DisplayMember = "Value";
      PersonList.ValueMember = "Key";
      PersonList.DataSource = new BindingSource(personListDictionary, null);
}

private void sortListBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Access personListDictionary value
}
```

I need only one solution. If I have to put dictionary inside `FillPersonList` method how can I access its value. Or if keep it as it is now how reload database without exception error.

Comment: use an array. sort the array. re-bind ....

Comment: Can you please write all the relevant code (all the one you are referring in the question)? Or, at least, the one triggering the error?

Comment: @MitchWheat Did you suggest to use array for passing value to sortListBox_TextChanged method?

Comment: Clean up the dictionary upon reloading data from database. Maybe the error was duplicate key in dict -you dont tell us exactly-

Comment: @har07 Yes. It is the problem. Actually I said ArguemntException error but forgot to mention the related message. Thanks and please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: You should have included your code to get the best answer. Deleting all the dictionary entries every time (same thing that re-associating the DataSource) might not be necessary at all. Actually, your whole approach (from the code you posted) seems that might be improved in various fronts. Next time you should be more clear regarding what you did (relevant code), the exact problem, constraints, etc. to get the best answer possible (not a temporary fix) and actually relevant information for future readers.

Comment: @varocarbas Sorry I can't realize that one. I will be more expressive next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer as requested, with pleasure :)

> The dictionary need to be cleaned up upon reloading data from database. Maybe the error was duplicate key in dictionary.